# Laravel foreach variable loop scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach, wiki

When I use Laravel blade file foreach loop, the variable is accessible after the foreach loop, whereas the scope of the variable should be only within the loop

```
@foreach($user->referral as $ref)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $ref->referral_amount }}</td>
    <td>{{ $ref->status }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

`$ref`: This variable is accessible outside endforeach loop after `@endforeach`

Comment: No dude you can't use `$ref` outside of loop.

Comment: It is accessible after the loop, tried it

Comment: No, the only reason that is possible is if you already send a $ref variable to your view from your controller/view-composer/..

Comment: @Christophvh I tried a foreach, and didn't have that variable passed from the controller

Comment: Nope, it's not accessible out of the loop. You can only use it within the loop!

Comment: I know it shouldn't be accessible, but I am able to access the variable outside the loop, no idea why @HirenGohel

Comment: If I access the variable before foreach, it says "Undefined variable", after loop (after @endforeach) it displays the value of last iteration

Comment: @MehravishTemkar why only access to last iteration value?

Comment: This is well-documented PHP behaviour and has nothing to do with Laravel nor Blade.

Comment: Because the value gets updated on the last iteration and then the loops ends, so the value of last iteration is what we get after the loop @MayurPanchal

Answer (score 7):

From [the `foreach` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> **Warning**
>
> Reference of a `$value` and the last array element remain even after the `foreach` loop. It is recommended to destroy it by `unset()`

So, if you want to destroy the reference, do this:

```
<?php unset($ref); ?>
```

Or:

```
@php unset($ref); @endphp
```

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to destroy it by unset()

```
 @php unset($ref); @endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem you can use unset() method of php for destroy a variables.

For that you can use this type of code inside your blade file after foreach loop.

```
<?php
// destroy a single variable
unset($foo);

// destroy a single element of an array
unset($bar['quux']);

// destroy more than one variable
unset($foo1, $foo2, $foo3);
?>
```

or

```
@php
// destroy a single variable
unset($foo);

// destroy a single element of an array
unset($bar['quux']);

// destroy more than one variable
unset($foo1, $foo2, $foo3);
@endphp
```